# javascript Cookie for every 24 hours in window open code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a simple popup code , it opens two sites with one click.

Now the problem is that it doesn't work for every 24 Hours. It works many many times a day.

Where is wrong in my own code? How can i solve this ?

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
  {
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}

function setCookie(c_name,value){
var exdays= 1;
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setHours(exdate.getHours() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function checkCookie(){
var username1=getCookie("tabligh1");
var usernam = "sendshod";
if(username1==null){
window.open('#','_parent','toolbar=1,location=1,directories=1,status=1,menubar=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1');
window.focus();
}
if(username1=="" | username1==null){
if(window.open('site adress1','_blank','toolbar=1,scrollbars=1,location=1,statusbar=1,menubar=1,resizable=1')){
window.focus();
setCookie("tabligh1",usernam);
}
}
if(username1=="" | username1==null){
if(window.open('site adress2','_blank','toolbar=1,scrollbars=1,location=1,statusbar=1,menubar=1,resizable=1')){
window.focus();
setCookie("tabligh1",usernam);
}
}
}
document.onclick = checkCookie;
if ((window.XMLHttpRequest == undefined) && (ActiveXObject != undefined)) window.onload = checkCookie;
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't work for every 24 Hours" mean?  I don't understand what the problem is.  Please describe how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 the problem is that the windows get open many times, The 24 Hour cookie not limit the time for opening the windows , I just wanted to open ONE Time , but it opens many time for each 24 hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setCookie()` function is setting the cookie to expire 1 hour from now, not 24 hours from now.

As you can see here in your code:

```
function setCookie(c_name, value) {
    var exdays = 1;
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setHours(exdate.getHours() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

You are setting the expiration time to one hour from the current time.  Perhaps you meant to increment the time by one day, not one hour?

Comment: Thanks, It was a bad mistake!